# How to fix 'No module named elasticsearch' error while using a Lambda function with a zip package containing elasticsearch module?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Have a Zip folder lambda-package -> contains 2 subfiles -> lambda-package(modules) and one file called lambda-package.py. so when uploaded the lambda-package zip file to Lambda function showing error as "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'elasticsearch'"

basically lambda-package(modules) contains elasticsearch module but still somehow showing error
[please find the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNvRk.png)

am new to AWS Lambda so can anyone help me on this.

i have installed "pip install elasticsearch" and also Verifyd the Deployment Package: Double-checked that the deployment package which i uploaded to Lambda  and contains the elasticsearch module. also Checked the File Name and Structure: to Ensure that Python file, containing the Lambda function code, is named lambda_function.py. because Lambda expects the file name to be exactly lambda_function.py by default. Additionally, at the top level of the deployment package have lambda_function.py file is places and not nested inside a subdirectory.
[please find the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlWgC.png)

[AWS console shows error in Test tab of Lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgDqd.png)